# Is this the correct way to create and post a mutipart form data in CakePhp3?

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to post a **mutipart form data in CakePhp3**. The form should contain a few information about the user (text fields) and an image.

I'm doing something like this:

```
$request = [
  'fistname'=>$user->firstname,
  'lastname'=>'$user->lastname',
  '_session'=>'$session'
];

$form = new FormData();
foreach ($request as $key => $value) {
  $form->add($key,$request);
}
$file = $form->addFile('upload',fopen(WWW_ROOT.'img/picture.png','r'));
$file->contentId('mypicture'); // <-- not sure what this is
$file->disposition('attachment');

$response = $http->post(
  $url,
  (string)$form,
  ['headers' => ['Content-Type' => $form->contentType()]]
);
```

Is this the correct way to create and post a mutipart form data in CakePhp3?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

If I post to my own server it seems to be working (thanks @Mary), but I get firstname and lastname replicated (this might be the problem):

```
object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest) {
trustProxy => false
...
[protected] data => [
    'fistname' => [
        'fistname' => 'Test',
        'lastname' => 'Test'
    ],
    'lastname' => [
        'fistname' => 'Test',
        'lastname' => 'Test'
    ],
    'upload' => [
        'tmp_name' => '/private/var/folders/g5/jjd1vc557bs21hq805lcxjk80000gn/T/phpAVXNqK',
        'error' => (int) 0,
        'name' => 'SELL5BAE2B6348272_gallery_1.png',
        'type' => 'image/png',
        'size' => (int) 200231
    ]
]
...
```

If I post to the API server it doesn't work.
I did the same with CURL and it works:

```
$filename = WWW_ROOT.'ufiles/medium/'.$img['image_1'];
$cFile = curl_file_create($filename);
$request = [
  '_operation'=>'uploadFile',
  'id'=>$ticket_id,
  '_session'=>$session,
  'file' => $cFile
];

try{
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$this->crm['endpoint']);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
  $response=curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close ($ch);
}catch(\Exception $e){
  $response = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterquestion: Does it work?

As you can see here, `$file->contentId()` sets the Content ID or part in a multipart form data request body:
https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Http/Client/FormDataPart.php#L114

I’m not sure about this, but I don’t think you have to set it as it doesn’t seem to be required for `multipart/form-data`:
https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xforms-20060314/slice11.html#serialize-form-data

---

**Edit**
I did some testing and: It. works. Here is what I tried:

```
use Cake\Http\Client;
use Cake\Http\Client\FormData;

public function test() {

    $request = [
        'fistname'=>'Test',
        'lastname'=>'Test'
    ];

    $form = new FormData();
    $http = new Client();

    foreach ($request as $key => $value) {
        $form->add($key,$request);
    }
    $file = $form->addFile('upload',fopen(WWW_ROOT.'img/awards.png','r'));
    $file->contentId('mypicture'); // <-- not sure what this is
    $file->disposition('attachment');

    $response = $http->post(
      'http://www.testurl.dev/test',
      (string)$form,
      ['headers' => ['Content-Type' => $form->contentType()]]
    );
    var_dump($response);
    exit;
}
```

Output of `var_dump($response)`:

```
object(Cake\Http\Client\Response)#150 (12) {
  ["code":protected]=>int(200)
  …
  ["headers":protected]=>array(12) {
    ["Date"]=>array(1) {
      [0]=>string(29) "Fri, 28 Sep 2018 12:44:31 GMT"
    }
    …
  }
}
```

Server access log output:

```
[28/Sep/2018:14:44:31 +0200] "POST /test HTTP/1.1" 200 6852 "-" "CakePHP"
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work and I don't understand why. I get no error/excepuions but my request does not even get to the server. If I remove $file = $form->addFile ... The request arrives to the server.

Comment: Can you inspect if `fopen(…)` returns you a valid handle? Is the file readable?

Comment: Already checked that: the file handler is valid and the file is readble

Comment: But in the request I notice there is a problem: firstname and lastname are replicated. See my edit.